# What are 'modal rhythm' and 'mensural rhythm'?

Tags: terminology, rhythm, medieval

The following is from Harvard Dictionary of Music 2nd Edit.

From the definition of 'Discant' (bold added):

> [...] The ideal of contrary motion was mentioned in the 13th-century "Tractatus de Discantu" (in J.-A.-L. de la Fage, *Essais*, i, 358; *CS* i, 311) but became an essential characteristic of discant theory only at the end of the 13th century, when **modal rhythm was replaced by
> mensural rhythm.**

Full page of context:

[image: page 263 of dictionary dirigent-discant]

I've never heard these two terms: mensural and modal rhythm. Google gave nothing, neither did Britannica.

What do these two terms mean?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the time to answer right now, but the phrases "rhythmic modes" and "mensural notation" may help guide you.

Comment: @Richard Thank you, rhytmic modes gave results, I edited the question thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you read the referenced section "[Modes, rhythmic]"?

Comment: Near the bottom of the first column: "but with the emphasis on strict measurement in modal rhythm [see **Modes, rhythmic**]."  Did you look up "Modes, rhythmic" in the same dictionary?

Comment: @Aaron and phoog; yes there's a brief definition. Let me make you a copy paste: Modal rhytm: 'A rhythm based on the rhythmic  modes.' But I really don't understand what this means (before opening the question)

Comment: Well, for certain the book's description isn't very helpful!

Comment: @Aaron also from the same book: Modal rhythm: Not until shortly before 
1200 did isometric rhythm become definitely 
established through the modal rhythm [see 
Modes, rhythmic] of the organa, clausulae, etc., 
of the school of Notre Dame. Credit for this important innovation must be ascribed to Leoninus. (and it goes on; it actually more or less answers the question). It's too long so I uploaded it https://ibb.co/m4yt338

Comment: That seems like it would supply the basis for a good answer. In case you aren't already familiar, it's permitted to answer your own question.

Comment: Orhan Torun: the link in your previous comment does not work for me.  I join @Aaron in encouraging you to write an answer describing what you've found.

Comment: @Aaron I'll, as soon as I feel confident to provide one; I'm still working on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

Modal rhythm used note linkage to indicate length. Various patterns of notes indicated how to play the following notes.

Mensural rhythm used note forms (minim, breve, semibreve, etc.); using like 2 semi-breves vs a breve to indicate binary rhythm and 3 semi-breves vs a breve to indicate ternary rhythm schemes.

These are well-described in Wikis and various music history books.